# Complementary MOSFET symbol in Multisim(Electronics Workbench)

Tags: mosfet, spice, multisim, mosfet-driver

It is just me or symbol for complementary mosfet pair in NI Multisim is wrong? And actually not just the symbol, but the function itself - it doesn't work as it is supposed to(or it's just me being stupid).
Here's the deal - the P-channel mosfet(top) is mirrored vertically, making its drain connected to Vcc, hence the internal diode starts to conduct and the whole thing doesn't make sense anymore. To provide evidence you can see the pin numbers and their meaning in properties.
I also tested it with simple circuit and yep - it doesn't work like it is meant to be.
Also the third picture is usual mosfet driver configuration.
So, questions are:
1) Maybe I don't get something and sometimes people put the P-channel mosfet another way around for some purpose?
2) Is it a mistake from developers and bug report should be written to NI?

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure does look wrong.

Here is the actual datasheet for the Fairchild NDS8852H:
http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/NDS8852H.pdf

Here is a link to a spice model.  Perhaps it could be manually edited into Multisim.
http://www.datasheetarchive.com/files/spicemodels/misc/spice_model_cd/vendor%20list/fairchild/nd/nds8852h.lib
If not editable you might copy the component, make the corrections, then save it to a similar named part.

If you report it to NI be sure to include the MultiSim version # your using.  Per the NI web site the latest version seems to be lucky 13.